# Cannot set EditorFor value (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I writing ASP.NET app

I have model like this

```
 public class InvitationMails
{
    [Key]
    public int Individ_Id { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Почта")]
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
}
```

And View like this

```
@model IEnumerable<SmartSolutions.Models.InvitationMails>
<div class="inner-div3">
<div class="right-welcome-div2">
    <table class="table">
        <tr style=" width: 100%">
            <th style="font-size: 20px;padding-left: 60px;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.To)
            </th>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 40px; width: 40px;">
                <a href='@Url.Action("Create", "InvitationMails")'>
                    <img style="object-fit: cover;" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/plus.png")' />
                </a>
                <input type="" value="Send"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 14px; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.To)
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: end;padding-top: 10px;">
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "InvitationMails", new {id = item.Individ_Id})'>
                        <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")' />
                    </a>
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "InvitationMails", new {id = item.Individ_Id})'>
                        <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Delete.png")' />
                    </a>
               </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to set also one `@Html.EditorFor` field and write it like this `@Html.EditorFor(model =>model.To)` but I have this error. I don't understood why, because I have `To` in my model

[image]

How I can solve this?

Comment: Why do you want `EditorFor()` - you do not even have a form so why would you create an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is IEnumerable, but "To" is property of its element.
You should get one element and then use EditorFor. 
For example:

```
EditorFor(model => model.First().To)
```

Comment: You should take into account whether the Model is an empty sequence. E.g, `@if (Model.Count() > 0){EditorFor(model => model.First().To)}`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a property of one item outside of the foreach block. Your model isn't one item, but many, so when you access the To property, you have to access it for an individual item within your model.